# Calculation of downscale factor for downsampling image using Rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio, resampling

I have image with resolution of 30cm in WGS84 EPSG 4326.
I want to down-scale the image to get the same image but with 50cm size of pixel.
I have used [Rasterio documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/rasterio/latest/rasterio.pdf) (pages 80-81) in order to downscale my image from 30cm to 50 cm.

This is the script I have used (explanation after):

```
#get downscale factor by divide 30/50 

dwnscale_factor = 30/50
with rasterio.open(urls[0]) as dataset:
    # resample data to target shape
    data = dataset.read(
        out_shape=(dataset.count,int(dataset.height * dwnscale_factor),int(dataset.width * dwnscale_factor)),
        resampling=Resampling.bilinear)
    # scale image transform
    transform = dataset.transform * dataset.transform.scale(
        (dataset.width / data.shape[-1]),
        (dataset.height / data.shape[-2])
        )
```

This works and creates image, but, **the image is in 1 meter resolution and not 50cm as requested.**

I believe I have mistake on the way I'm calculating the down-scale factor. Looking for ways I can get my image resampled from 30cm to 50cm.

Comment: 30cm and WGS84 is an unlikely combination. Resampling to 50cm seems less than optimal (60cm would cause less interpolation problems).

Comment: @Vince thank you for your answer! can you elaborate about it? (why 30cm won't work in WGS84)

Comment: WGS84 is in degrees, so every row is a different width. The "0.3m" is an approximation, that can be off by as much as, well, 0.29m. To get a raster into degrees, it needs to be deprojected and interpolated (which will have impacted quality as well). If you then resample at an uneven pixel ratio, well, not much of the original data is left.

Comment: @Vince what if I'll reproject to CRS that uses meters? Like 3857. And then go back to 4326? (Assuming I'll still lose original data)

Comment: Reprojection will often rotate pixels, and Web Mercator doesn't use actual meters, so that's a full stop. Resampling reduces data quality, but judicious selection of the new resolution can preserve as much as possible. I'm simply suggesting you resample to a multiple of the previous resolution (and to be aware of the difference between the units of geographic and projected coordinate systems).